# Keypress event handling in android

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

In my application I want save date and time when user save contact detail.

through which I can know date and time that when user has saved particular contact details.

Thank you.

Comment: i dont understand what you want to say . please give more description about your question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use KeyEvent class documented here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html